# Marker(overlay) of the google map disappears while changing the orientation of the device

Tags: android, orientation, overlay, android-mapview

I am using the following code for showing the marker in the current location...but when i change the orientation of the device marker disappears..?

```
         List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
            Drawable drawable = Activity.this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
            MyItemizedOverlay itemizedOverlay = new MyItemizedOverlay(drawable ,Activity.this);

            GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint( (int)(location.getLatitude()*1000000),
                    (int)(location.getLongitude()*1000000));

         OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "Current Location :","+acTextView.getText());

            itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
            mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);
            MapController mapController = mapView.getController();

            mapController.animateTo(point);
            mapController.setZoom(14);
```

How to handle the orientation in the mapview..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, when orientation of device changes the Activity restart..I put the following attribute in my manifest.xml and my problem is solved now :

```
  android:configChanges="orientation"
```